# Помогите, пожалуйста, в ORACLE разобраться

Tags: oracle

> Не передан номер обеспечения для удаления ORA-06512: at "IY00444.ERRORS", line 130 ORA-06512: at "IY00444.PROC_LD_SAP", line 4613 ORA-06512: at line 1 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:111) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:330) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:287) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:744) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:217) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:968) at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1189) at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3369) at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3475) at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4399) at com.is.credits.application.Credit_application_service.proc_PROC_LDFORM_SaveGR(Credit_application_service.java:1221) at com.is.credits.application.Credit_application_service.register_loan_form_and_facility(Credit_application_service.java:770) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor180.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212) at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117) at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40) at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114) at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:876) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:618) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1790) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в ошибке.

Comment: Что в этой строке? com.is.credits.application.Credit_application_service.proc_PROC_LDFORM_SaveGR(Credit_application_service.java:1221)

Comment: ВОТ Я НА РАБОТУ НЕ ДАВНО УСТРОИЛСЯ И МНЕ СРАЗУ ДАЛИ ЭТУ ОШИБКУ ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ ЕЩЕ НЕ ЗНАЮ И НЕКТО НЕ ПОМОГАЕТ

Comment: как минимум, не КРИЧАТЬ и не делать АРФАГРАФИЧЕСКИХ ашибок. И не думать. что все обязаны тебе помагать

Comment: не я проста спрашиваю как начинающий программист кто может помочь а чо ты так сразу злишся

Comment: ну это ошибка выдаваемая самим приложением, а не стандартная ошибка Oracle. надо открывать исходный код указанных в сообщении процедур и смотреть что не получила вызываемая процедура и вызывающий код, почему он не передал то, что она ожидала получить. Без исходного когда приложения никто ничего не скажет. Возможно придется спускаться в код самого приложения, ошибка вполне может быть и за пределами БД.

Comment: ок спасибо огромное